# Adding Hover Effect to p5.js Data Visualization not working?

Tags: visualization, p5.js

I'm currently working on a data visualization in `p5.js`. The data is stored in a `.csv` and the values are mapped to constants. These constants are then used to manipulate the position, color and size of the circles.

##### Here is the code so far:

```js
let table;

function preload(){
  table = loadTable("assets/songs_normalize.csv", "csv", "header");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas (3000,3000);
  background(133,124,222);
  for (let r = 0; r < table.getRowCount( ); r++) {
    const artist = table.getString(r, "artist");
    const song = table.getString(r, "song");
    const duration = table.getNum(r, "duration_ms");
    const year = table.getNum(r,"year");
    const tempo = table.getNum (r,"tempo");
    const energy = table.getNum (r,"energy");
    const popularity = table.getNum(r,"popularity");
    const y = map(year,1998,2020,50,2950);
    const x = map(tempo,60,211,50,2950);
    const size = map(duration,0, 484146, 0, 100); 
    const color = map (popularity,0,89,0,255)
    const opacity = map(energy,0.05,1,0,255)
    let circleColor = colorfill(color/2,-color,color);
    circleColor.setAlpha(opacity);
    noStroke();
    fill (circleColor);
    circle(x,y,size);
  }
}
  
function colorfill(r,g,b) {
  return color(r, g, b);
}
```

##### And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Now I want to add a simple hover effect.

I found a tutorial online that seems to do just what I need but when applied to my project, no circles are drawn:

```js
let table;

function preload(){
  table = loadTable("assets/songs_normalize.csv", "csv", "header");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas (3000,3000);
  background(133,124,222);
  for (let r = 0; r < table.getRowCount( ); r++) {
    const artist = table.getString(r, "artist");
    const song = table.getString(r, "song");
    const duration = table.getNum(r, "duration_ms");
    const year = table.getNum(r,"year");
    const tempo = table.getNum (r,"tempo");
    const energy = table.getNum (r,"energy");
    const popularity = table.getNum(r,"popularity");
    const y = map(year,1998,2020,50,2950);
    const x = map(tempo,60,211,50,2950);
    const size = map(duration,0, 484146, 0, 100);

    const color = map (popularity,0,89,0,255)
    const opacity = map(energy,0.05,1,0,255)

    let circleColor = colorfill(color/2,-color,color);
    circleColor.setAlpha(opacity);
    noStroke();
    //fill (circleColor);
    //circle(x,y,size);
  }
}

function draw() {}

 //hover
    
    
    let dis = dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y);
    if (dis < 5) {
      fill(0);
      
      noStroke();
      circle(x, y, size);
      //draw information
      text(artist,x,y);
      text(song,x,y+10);
    } else {
      fill(circleColor);
    
      noStroke();
      circle(x, y, size);
    }
  
function colorfill(r,g,b) {
  return color(r, g, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the csv file while posting the question , However i managed to find that on kaggle [csv](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ashvanths/statistical-analysis-of-top-hits-in-spotify/data) .

Here is your solution - [click here](https://editor.p5js.org/vignesh2002/sketches/mbwG3njrq)

There are several problems with your code

1. for Hover effects to work on canvas , we need to check the distance between the points on every frame , so the hover code must be inside draw function (your draw function is empty)
2. to check the distance between your mouse and each circle their co-ordinates and size must be stored somewhere , In the solution i stored them in an array of objects named songs